# Javascript operator issue. Value needs to be at least 4 and an even number

Tags: javascript, operators

I am updating an old script by adding RAID 10 configuration.

However I cannot get it to function properly. The best I could achieve is below.

```
if (parseInt(document.form_config.txtNumberOfDisks.value)%2 != 0 && strRaidType == "RAID10") {
    strRaidType = "uRAID10";
}
```

This works, but also allows a 2 disk setup in with RAID 10. Obviously this is incorrect, because RAID 10 needs at least 4 disks (and an equal amount).

I already tried changing %2 to %4, but that requires multiples of 4 disks, so that's incorrect.

Any ideas?

Comment: There is no single operator that does this. Use `val % 2 == 0 && val >= 4`

Comment: please add some use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Create RAID "minimums" map:

```
var raidDisksMap = {"RAID0": 2, "RAID1": 2, "RAID5": 3, "RAID10": 4};
var disksAmount = parseInt(document.form_config.txtNumberOfDisks.value);

if (disksAmount >= raidDisksMap[strRaidType] && disksAmount % 2 == 0) {
    strRaidType = "uRAID10";
    ...
}
```

Comment: When I use this, I can enter every amount of disks for RAID10, including 0?

Comment: You meant `raidDisksMap[strRaidType]` instead of `strRaidType["RAID10"]`?

Comment: @Bergi, yes, sure ... that was a crazy typo. Thanks

Comment: @HudsonHawk, you enter any number, but to pass the condition it should be bigger(equal) than the minimum of a certain RAID from  `raidDisksMap`

Comment: Well changed it several times and applied it, but didn't help or work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @HudsonHawk, have you tried to replace `disksAmount % 2 != 0` with `disksAmount % 2 == 0` ?